# Add page break at Column Level in RDLC Report

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I am stuck into a problem....
I am filling my Table with Dataset with FIXED rows but Dynamic Columns.
My Requirement is that I need to have a page break  after 5 columns...

Eg:

```
  Product Name     2003  2004  2005   2006  2007 

  Mobile            10    15    20      19   17
  Laptop             55    2    3       17   10
  Tablet             10    10   25       4    9
```

Similarly on next page , I should have

```
  Product Name     2008  2009  2010   2011  2012

  Mobile            50     5    2      19   25
  Laptop             5    2    30       17   100
  Tablet            10    10   25       4    19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't got anyone's reply till now ... :-(

But my problem is solved :

I followed this link : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrishays/archive/2004/07/23/horizontaltables.aspx

Above link also hade the HorizontalTable.rdl attached...

I just adjusted my fields,Dataset and groupnames... It is working like charm...!!!!

Thanks Chris..!!!

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You could create secondary data source and use it to filter the main one - with one record per "page". So, you would create "wrapper" report where you push all the data, add table to it with single column where you would drop subreport where you only push data filtered by the values in the record of the secondary "wrapper" table.

Comment: Can you please give a detailed way on how to do this?